# Не работают два условия из трех

Tags: php, mysql

Не сооблюдаются эти условия, оно не выводит сообщение, а если выводит, то лепит на другое сообщение и в БД, конечно же, заносит пробелы в username, то же самое и второе условие пустые строки вводит в базу и если выводит сообщение, то лепит на другое

```
if (preg_match("/\\s/", $username['username']) && $newusername['newusername'] == true) {
    echo 'логин не должен содержать пробелов';
}
if (empty($username['username']) && $newusername['newusername']) {
    echo 'пустое поле';
}
```

Ниже полный код

```
<?php
include 'core/init.php';
protect_page();
include 'includes/overall/header.php';
if (isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['newusername'])) {
    $username    = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $newusername = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['newusername']);
    $sql         = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(username) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '" . $_POST['newusername'] . "';");
    $result      = mysql_result($sql, 0);
    if ($result > 0) {
        echo "Ошибка, логин существует";
    } else {
        echo (mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `username` = '$newusername' WHERE `username` = '$username'")) ? "Данные успешно обновлены!" : "Произошла ошибка при обновлении данных";
    }

    if (preg_match("/\\s/", $username['username']) && $newusername['newusername'] == true) {
        echo 'логин не должен содержать пробелов';
    }
    if (empty($username['username']) && $newusername['newusername']) {
        echo 'пустое поле';
    }
}
?>
   <h1>пользователи!</h1>
<?php

$ath = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `type`=0");
if ($ath) {
    // Определяем таблицу и заголовок
    echo "<table border=1>";
    echo "<tr><td>user_id</td><td>логин</td><td>пароль</td><td>имя</td><td>email</td></tr>";
    // Так как запрос возвращает несколько строк, применяем цикл
    while ($author = mysql_fetch_array($ath)) {
        echo "<tr><td>" . $author['user_id'] . " </td><td>" . $author['username'] . " </td><td>" . $author['password'] . "
            &nbsp </td><td>" . $author['first_name'] . " </td><td>" . $author['email'] . "
            &nbsp </td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "<p><b>Error: " . mysql_error() . "</b><p>";
    exit();
}

?>
<form action="" method="post">
    <ul>
        <li>логин*:
            <br>
            <input type="text" name="username">
        </li>
        <li>изменить логин*:
            <br>
            <input type="text" name="newusername">
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="submit" value="сохранить изменения">
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
<?php
include 'includes/overall/footer.php';
?>
```

Comment: Зачем вы весь код то выложили, как я усну то теперь...

Comment: [depricated](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-connect.php)

    Данное расширение устарело, начиная с версии PHP 5.5.0, и будет 
    удалено в будущем. Используйте вместо него MySQLi или PDO_MySQL. 
    Смотрите также инструкцию MySQL: выбор API и соответствующий FAQ 
    для получения более подробной информации. Альтернативы для данной 
    функции:

[mysqli_connect()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysqli-connect.php)

[PDO::__construct()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.construct.php)

Comment: И это вот тут ни ... не единственная проблема. Чего только стоят одни пароли в базе, в ОТКРЫТОМ виде, (сомневаюсь, что в закрытой сети) вываливающиеся на дисплей, чума.

Comment: вы бы еще через сто лет ответили, но не беспокойтесь дамы и господа сейчас все работает на высшем уровне по последнему слову программированию и работает потрясающи на сервере, так что можете спать спокойно XDDDD

Answer (score 1):

Здравствуйте, вроде нашел ошибку `$newusername['newusername']`, а как я понял это не массив,а обычная переменная `$newusername`. А также  `$username['username']`, а надо `$username`. В итоге:

```
if (preg_match("/\\s/", $username) && $newusername==true) 
    echo 'логин не должен содержать пробелов';
if (empty($username) && $newusername) 
      echo 'пустое поле';
```

Comment: абсолютно ничего не поменялось

Comment: Тогда в самом начале сделайте exit($_POST['username'].'|||'. $_POST['newusername']); Если оно выведет то что вы ввели, значит передача прошла успешно, если нет, то возможно у Вас не закрыта тега <form> - више этой формы, бывает что на странички 1-2 формы сразу и одно из них  забывают закрыть и данные передаются через другой метод.

Comment: exit($_POST['username'].'|||'. $_POST['newusername']);
написал я это в самом начале мне толь ||| зеленого цвета вывело

Comment: У вас на страничке есть еще формы? А ну давайте попробуем на эксперимент: `exit($_GET['username'].'|||'. $_GET['newusername']);`   .Ситуация не изменилась?

Comment: ничего не поменялось, а вон весь код сверху я выложил

Comment: Я Вам не точно обьяснил. Извините спешил. Сейчас уберите мой код, обновте страничку, и заполните поля.После того как заполнили поля в верху вставляете этот код `exit($_POST['username'].'|||'. $_POST['newusername']);`. Сохраняете и и нажимаете на кнопку "сохранить изменения"

Comment: Если вы сделали все как я Вам сказал, значит что-то мешает передать данные. Я сейчас должен отойти, если Вам не кто не поможет, то напишите в скайп node_xaker

Comment: хорошо я вас добавлю

Answer (score 0):

регулярное выражение "/\s/" внутри, мне кажется, должен быть один слэш

Answer (score 0):

Соответствие шаблону нового имени пользователя, необходимо проверять до любых манипуляций с БД, потому как в этом пропадет необходимость, да и для здоровья БД лучше.

```
/*
Удалить пробелы (или другие символы) из начала и конца строки
Могут появиться, если логин был вставлен со стороннего ресурса
*/
$newusername = trim($_POST['newusername']);

/*
Проверить соответствие шаблону:
1) только буквы латиницы; 
2) логин может начинаться с заглавной;
3) длина не больше 16-ти символов, вместе с заглавной.
*/
if(!preg_match('/^[A-Z]{0,1}[a-z]{0,15}$/', $newusername)){
    echo 'Недопустимое имя пользователя';
    exit;
}
```

Comment: верю на слово что это работает=)

Comment: Это сарказм? :)

Comment: Точно... Пустая строка то проскочит. Всё, пора заканчивать с программированием... не моё.